# Passing local variable in Razor view by JavaScript to java script function and then to C# method

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to pass `@survey` which is object of `class Survey` to the JavaScript function `SubmitClick` and then to the `SubmitSurvey` in `PersonController.cs`

My button: when clicked it passes arguments to `javascript:SubmitClick`

```
<button class='mybutton' type='button' onclick="javascript:SubmitClick(@Model.Item1.Id, @survey);">Save Survey</button>
```

and JavaScript function:

```
function SubmitClick(pid, sid) {     
    var url = '@Url.Action("SubmitSurvey", "Person")';
    $.post(url, { personId: pid, survey: sid }, function (data) {
        alert('updated' + pid);
    });
}
```

and method to which I want to pass `@survey`:

```
  public void SubmitSurvey(int personId, Survey survey) {

        }
```

The result is:

[image]

I want to point out that passing `@survey.Id`(int) worked so the only problem is passing the `@survey`.

Error pop ups  at passing arguments to java script function.

---

**EDIT**

The button is inside foreach loop and the model is little bit complex. Can I just serialize it inside a loop?

I pass List of Survey to the view from here:

```
 public ActionResult _Survey1(int id) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PASSED ID: " + id);
            Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
            //Passing a Tuple to Partial View, I want to pass copies further I use copying constructor
            List<Survey> localSurveysCopy = new List<Survey>();
            foreach (Survey survey in db.Surveys) {
                localSurveysCopy.Add(new Survey(survey));
            }
            var tuple = new Tuple<Person, List<Survey>>(person, localSurveysCopy) { };
            return PartialView(tuple);
 }
```

The view:

```
 @using WebApplication2.Models
@model   System.Tuple<Person, List<Survey>>

<hr />
<h1>Surveys</h1>

<input type="button" id="Coll" value="Collapse" onclick="javascript:CollapseDiv()" />

@{int i = 1;}
@foreach (var survey in Model.Item2) {
    using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <h2>Survey @(i)</h2>
        <p />
        @Html.EditorFor(x => survey.Questions)
        <button class='mybutton' type='button' onclick="javascript:SubmitClick(@Model.Item1.Id,  @Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(survey));">Save Survey</button>
    }
    i++;
    <hr style="background-color:rgb(126, 126, 126);height: 5px" />
}
<hr />
```

The script. I think I had to pass variable directly as I have many surveys and many buttons:

```
function SubmitClick(pid, sid) {     
    var url = '@Url.Action("SubmitSurvey", "Person")';
    var objSurvey = $.parseJSON(sid);
    $.post(url, { personId: pid, survey: objSurvey }, function (data) {
        alert('updated person' + pid + ' survey ' + sid);
    });
}
```

I get:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll
```

The class Survey looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.Models {


    public class Survey {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { set; get; }

        public Survey() { }
        public Survey(Survey survey) {
            Id = survey.Id;
            Questions = new List<Question>();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SURVEY " + survey.Questions == null);
           foreach (Question question in survey.Questions) {
                Questions.Add(new Question(question));
            }
        }
    }
    public class Question {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string QuestionText { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { set; get; }
        public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
        public string SelectedAnswer { set; get; } //this field is SET after clicking SAVE button

        public Question() { }

        public Question(Question question) {
            Id = question.Id;
            QuestionText = question.QuestionText;
            Answers = question.Answers;
            Survey = question.Survey;
            SelectedAnswer = "";
        }
    }
    public class Answer {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string AnswerText { set; get; }
        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to send back the `@survey` object ? If `@survey` has property `Answer` and its value is empty, then the user makes changes the `Answer` input `<input name="Answer" type="text" />` in the UI into `Some Value`, the submit button will not send the `Some Value`, but empty value, what you need to do is serialize the form, not sending the `@survey`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just pass C# object to JS and post it back.

You should:

- Convert your object to JSON and pass it to JS. I advise to use [Newtonsoft.JSON](http://json.codeplex.com/) for it.

**controller:**

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(survey);
```

**markup:**

```
<button class='mybutton' type='button' onclick="javascript:SubmitClick(@Model.Item1.Id, @json);">Save Survey</button>
```

- Then from JS you should post JSON to your MVC controller and MVC will deserialize it your C# object.

**markup:**

```
function SubmitClick(pid, sid) {     
    var objSurvey = $.parseJSON(sid);
    var url = '@Url.Action("SubmitSurvey", "Person")';
    $.post(url, { personId: pid, survey: objSurvey }, function (data) {
        alert('updated' + pid);
    });
}
```

**controller:**

```
  public void SubmitSurvey(int personId, Survey survey) {       }
```

**UPDATED:**

Your Survey entity cannot be serialized correctly because of cycle references between classes. So you have few options here:

- use **[JsonIgnore]** attribute to ignore backreferences. (So you should mark Survey property inside Question class with this attribute, Question property inside Answer class and so on) Please keep in mind that **these fields will be not serialized to JS and deserialized back to C# objects**.
- create separate model without cycle references for serialization and use it when convert to JSON.

Comment: I posted an edit to the OP. I didn't post it before because I wanted to keep the question simple. The deal is that I have many surveys in the button and I get serialization errors maybe due virtual properties. Please have a look at edit.

Comment: Just wondering why did you write @Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model) and not @Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(survey) in your razor markup? You should pass serialized survey and not whole Model.

Comment: You are right I am just dealing with this problem for almost a week now. I made a mistake. I corrected it edited the OP I get the same errors. I commented the content of `function SubmitClick(pid, sid) {` to be sure that exceptions are thrown here `  <button class='mybutton' type='button' onclick="javascript:SubmitClick(@Model.Item1.Id,  @Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(survey));">Save Survey</button>` Maybe lazy loading is a reason? I'll try to make try catch inside a view.

Comment: I don't know how to make try-catch around html in Razor view. It won't help.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong.

Basically when you do `@survey`, you are looking at a server side code. At the client side, this `@survey`, which is an instance of a strongly typed clr class, is converted to string, and you know what happens when you convert and object to string, you get its Type in string i.e

```
@survey.ToString() == "WebApplications2.Models.Survey"
```

obviously it is wrong cause, your button tag's markup, at the end, effectively becomes :

```
<button class='mybutton' type='button' 
         onclick="javascript:SubmitClick(@Model.Item1.Id, 
                                     WebApplications2.Models.Survey);">
        Save Survey
</button>
```

You should basically first serialize your `@survey` object at the server side and store it in a hidden variable i.e.

```
@Html.Hidden("hdnSurvey", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))
```

and use this hidden variable inside your javascript

i.e.

```
function SubmitClick(pid) {     
    var objSurvey = $.parseJSON( $('#hdnSurvey').val());

    var url = '@Url.Action("SubmitSurvey", "Person")';

    $.post(url, { personId: pid, survey: objSurvey }, function (data) {
        alert('updated' + pid);
    });
}
```

Comment: I am wondering why do you use hidden field for JSON? I think you can pass it directly to JS function and it will parsed as JS object, right?

Comment: you are correct absolutely. just to make it simple and to make a point that, it has nothing to do with the way you pass it or the javascript function

Comment: I posted an edit to the OP. I didn't post it before because I wanted to keep the question simple. The deal is that I have many surveys in the button and I get serialization errors maybe due virtual properties. Please have a look at edit.

Answer (score 0):

Sending back the `@survey` variable is pointless, the changes from the UI will not be reflected from the variable, but from HTML input, what you really need is serializing the form.

Here is a complete solution for what you really need.

**Model**

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
}
public class Survey
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { set; get; }
}
public class Question
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string QuestionText { set; get; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { set; get; }
    public int SelectedAnswerId { set; get; } // Notice that I change it into int not string
}
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string AnswerText { set; get; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var person = new Person { Id = 1 };
    var survey = new Survey
    {
        Id = 12,
        Questions = new List<Question> 
        {
            new Question 
            {
                Id = 34,
                QuestionText = "What is your favorite language?",
                Answers = new List<Answer>
                {
                    new Answer { Id = 56, AnswerText = "A#" },
                    new Answer { Id = 57, AnswerText = "B#" },
                    new Answer { Id = 58, AnswerText = "C#" }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var model = new Tuple<Person, List<Survey>>(person, new List<Survey> { survey });
    return View(model);
} 

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitSurvey(int personId, Survey survey)
{
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model  Tuple<Person, List<Survey>>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Surveys</h2>

@{int i = 1;}
@foreach (var survey in Model.Item2)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <h3>Survey @(i++)</h3>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => survey.Id)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => survey.Questions)
        <button class="mybutton" type="button">Save Survey</button>
    }
}

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(".mybutton").click(function () {
            var personId = "@Model.Item1.Id";
            var survey = $(this).closest("form").serialize();
            var data = survey + "&personId=" + personId;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  "@Url.Action("SubmitSurvey", "Survey")", 
                data: data,
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("submitted :" + data.success);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>    
}
```

**EditorTemplates/Question.cshtml**

```
@model Question
<h3>@Model.QuestionText </h3>

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
@foreach (var a in Model.Answers)
{
    <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(b => b.SelectedAnswerId, a.Id) @a.AnswerText</label>
}
```

**Result**

If the user selected `B#` on the first survey on the first question, the submitted survey will return `SelectedAnswerId` as 57. The other properties like `Answers` and `QuestionText` are null and they're not important for saving so let it be.

[image: Result]